# Configure mysql to connect in ejabberd

Tags: mysql, ejabberd

I am using ejabberd 15.09 and mysql 14.14, i am changing the ejabberd.yml to connect mysql, for that:

-**old configure**:

auth_method: internal

mod_last
mod_offline
mod_roster
mod_vcard
mod_privacy
mod_private
mod_pubsub

%%open: odbc_pool_size: 20
%%open: odbc_keepalive_interval: 30

-**new configure**:

auth_method: odbc

odbc_type: mysql
odbc_server: "localhost"
odbc_database: "ejabberd"
odbc_username: "root"
odbc_password: "xxx"

mod_last_odbc
mod_offline_odbc
mod_roster_odbc
mod_vcard_odbc
mod_privacy_odbc
mod_private_odbc
mod_pubsub_odbc

odbc_pool_size: 20
odbc_keepalive_interval: 30

**then i used mysql to create database"ejabberd":**
mysql> create database ejabberd;

**While restart server, it produced the following error：**
2015-10-30 16:28:52.399 [error] <0.3145.0>@ejabberd_odbc:log:666 p1_mysql_conn: Failed changing to database "ejabberd" : "#42000Unknown database 'ejabberd'"
2015-10-30 16:28:52.399 [error] <0.386.0>@ejabberd_odbc:log:666 p1_mysql_conn: post_start error failed_changing_database
2015-10-30 16:28:52.399 [info] <0.386.0>@ejabberd_odbc:connecting:270 mysql connection failed:
** Reason: failed_changing_database

**How to resolve the issue？**

Comment: the error says "Unknown database ejabberd". Did you created the database with the name 'ejabberd'??

Comment: i used mysql to create database"ejabberd": mysql> create database ejabberd;

Comment: now ,i download the mysql file(mysql_recv.erl, mysql_conn.erl, mysql_auth.erl, mysql.hrl, mysql.erl) and compiled them, then start server, the err log for that :

Comment: gen_mod:start_module:106 Problem starting the module mod_pubsub_odbc for host <<"liwei-ubuntu">> 
 options: [{access_createnode,pubsub_createnode},
           {ignore_pep_from_offline,true},
           {last_item_cache,false},
           {plugins,[<<"flat">>,<<"hometree">>,<<"pep">>]}]
 error: undef

Comment: i find that : while mod_pubsub_odbc is chaged to mod_pubsub ,ok. but while adding "user@AAA" also "user@BBB" (if the virtual host "BBB" exists) is added。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you need to compile ejabberd with the MySQL support as:

```
./configure --enable-odbc --enable-mysql
```

If you want to connect the mysql, then you need create tables using the supplied script

```
mysql < /path/to/mysql.sql
```

Comment your `internal` authentication method (auth_method) and add the `ODBC` authentication method.

```
# auth_method: internal ## Commented this line
auth_method: ODBC ## Added this line
```

Now you need to have a connection to MySQL

```
odbc_type: mysql
odbc_server: "localhost"
odbc_port: 3306 # the default
odbc_database: "mydb"
odbc_username: "user1"
odbc_password: "userpassword"
odbc_pool_size: 5
```

You can read the description for the options [here](http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#relational-databases).

Add `_odbc` to modules you wish to use the mysql database

```
mod_offline_odbc instead of mod_offline
```

If you see the error of your [3rd comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33433851/configure-mysql-to-connect-in-ejabberd?noredirect=1#comment54725082_33433851), then remove `_odbc` from that module.

Now Restart the server.

Comment: ok， "mod_offline_odbc" change to "mod_offline：db_type: odbc" .

Comment: @李李微 I just gave an example with `mod_offline` module how to use the mysql for the modules. You can also add it to other modules which you want.

Comment: yes. now i add it to every diffrent modules,eg:
host_config:
  "example.com":
    odbc_type: mysql
    odbc_server: "localhost"
    odbc_database: "xxx"
    odbc_username: "xxx"
    odbc_password: "xxx"
    auth_method: odbc
    modules:
      mod_xxx:
        db_type: odbc
      mod_xxx:
        db_type: odbc
     ....

thank you!

Comment: @李李微 Great. If the answer is useful, you can upvote. So that other users with same issue will find answer easily

Comment: Is there a way for me make a global `db_type: odbc`?